# Python variable webelement/list to .txt Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, qwebelement

I would like to know the function to transform a list / webelement variable into .txt
with the code below I can only read the file on my console en.txt but not save it on my pc.

```
recuperation_nom = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title-3")

for resultat_nom in recuperation_nom:
    print(resultat_nom.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open `.txt` file in access mode `'a'`, then write each line into it.

```
recuperation_nom = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title-3")

with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.truncate(0)
    for resultat_nom in recuperation_nom:
        f.write(f"{resultat_nom.text}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's perfect for me it works!

Comment: I finally encountered an error indeed when I use your code my 'output' file contains duplicate values, ie I have twice each line but I would like to display the name only once .. .I don't know if I am very clear ...

Comment: Delete the file after each use since it's append.

Comment: @VictorMirault you can use <file>.truncate(0) method to clear contents of file whenever you run that code. I edited answer, check it out.